# Button with gradient outside border

Tags: html, css, button

How can I achieve the next thing in CSS to a < a >  element ?

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKEML.png)

I managed to do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/25abxak1/

-- first of , I need the content to be wider and second , I want the first color to go above the border , just like in the picture.

I'm a begginer in `CSS` and I really need help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` on `a`, and for black part you can use `:before` pseudo-element. You should also set `padding-left` on `a` to `width of :before + padding-right` so that text is centered.

```css
a {
  color: #C46439;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #D2D1D1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Centered text</a>
```

You can also use `linear-gradient` and set black part to `20%` or something similar.

```css
a {
  color: #C46439;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 20%, white 20%, white 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #D2D1D1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Centered text</a>
```

Comment: He is asking for a hyper link

Comment: @katamarayudu Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: for infos, you can also play with background-clip and padding https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qmbKqN feel free to add it (code snippet) to your answer if you wish to

Comment: I just realized that the black part has the border of the main element. I tried putting a border on :before as well but it stays inside the big gray border.